# Function that transforms input file based on a numpy poly1d function

Tags: python, python-2.x, numpy

I have written a function that gets a function as input (acquired from `numpy.poly1d`). The function has access to the GUI variables `self.batch` and `self.inputFile`, these variables specify if the function is called in batch mode or not and what the current inputFile (for transformation is).

My main concerns are:

- Would you understand the function based on my documentation?
- Is vectorizing only the values to be transformed correct?
- Is the function in general correct (meaning pythonic?)

The function:

```
def transformFile(self, f):
    """ This function gets a single function as input, reads the
    raw data file and transforms the read m/z values in the raw data
    file with the given function. The transformed m/z values are 
    stored in a calibrated_<inputfile>.xy file (if program is running
    in batchProcess mode) or asks the user for a filepath to save
    the calibrated file (if program is running in single spectrum mode).

    INPUT: a numpy polynomial (poly1d) function
    OUTPUT: a calibrated data file
    """
    # Prepare variables required for transformation
    outputBatch = []
    mzList = []
    intList = []
    with open (self.inputFile,'r') as fr:
        if self.batch == False:
            output = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename()
            if output:
                pass
            else:
                tkMessageBox.showinfo("File Error","No output file selected")
                return
        else: 
            parts = os.path.split(str(self.inputFile))
            output = "calibrated_"+str(parts[-1])
        if self.log == True:
            with open('MassyTools.log','a') as fw:
                fw.write(str(datetime.now())+"\tWriting output file: "+output+"\n")
        for line in fr:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            values = line.split()
            mzList.append(float(values[0]))
            intList.append(int(values[1]))
        # Transform python list into numpy array
        mzArray = numpy.array(mzList)
        newArray = f(mzArray)
        # Prepare the output as a list
        for index, i in enumerate(newArray):
            outputBatch.append(str(i)+" "+str(intList[index])+"\n")
        # Join the output list elements
        joinedOutput = ''.join(outputBatch)
        with open(output,'w') as fw:
            fw.write(joinedOutput)
        if self.log == True:
            with open('MassyTools.log','a') as fw:
                fw.write(str(datetime.now())+"\tFinished writing output file: "+output+"\n")
```